# How to read files starting with ph:// as base64 string with React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-fs

I'm trying to read image files starting with `ph://` and convert them to base64 string with RNFS but unfortunately I get `ENOENT: no such file or directory` error.

How can I read these files and convert them to base64?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-native-convert-ph-asset](https://github.com/jzyds/react-native-convert-ph-asset)

```
import RNConvertPhAsset from 'react-native-convert-ph-asset';

const convertLocalIdentifierToAssetLibrary = async (localIdentifier) => {
  return await RNHeicConverter.convert({
    // options
    path: localIdentifier,
  });
};
```

and then use react-native-fs to convert it to base64

```
 const base64 = await RNFS.readFile(newpath.path, 'base64');[enter link description here][2]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use your `ph://` uri for an image from your local device, you can use the uri option on the Image component from React-Native. You will see this in action in my code sample, below. But if you need to convert to base64 to get something like a `file:///` prefix to your uri then you can still use RNFS.

If you are on iOS, you can do something like the following with RNFS to convert the file path from `ph://` to `file:///`:

```
<TouchableHighlight
  onPress={async () => {
    const destPath = RNFS.CachesDirectoryPath + '/MyPic.jpg';
    
    try {
      await RNFS.copyAssetsFileIOS(imageUri, destPath, 0, 0);
      console.log('destPath', destPath);
      } catch (error) {console.log(error);} 

      navigation.navigate('SelectedPicture', {
        uri: 'file://' + destPath,
          });
   }}>
    <Image source={{uri: imageUri}} style={styles.image} />
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Note that the path may not begin with "file://" so I added it in manually.

See here for more detail: https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs#ios-only-copyassetsvideoiosvideouri-string-destpath-string-promisestring

I believe RNFS.copyAssetsFileIOS does something similar to `react-native-convert-ph-asset` under the hood.